# Using trigonometry functions to find a number's integer factors?

Tags: trigonometry, factoring

So I found out that using these two equations:

```
x*y=n
sin(x*pi)=sin(n*pi/x)=0
```

a list of factors to n could be found.

currently, the best single function that finds all **integer** factors is
$$
\left|\cos\left(x\pi\right)\right|+\left|\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{x}\right)\right|=2
$$

this is the best I could find.
My question is, is this a reliable way to find factors for n, and if not, what are some better ways?

Comment: @matanPleblist Your last function 'predicts' the factors to $n$ surprisingly well. I plotted it using [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/y7icuhuton) and it shows that $0$ has all integers as factors, $1$'s only factor is itself, and *appears* to have only one zero when $n$ is prime.

Comment: I don't have any conclusive proof that this works, but the experimental evidence suggests it might work for all integers.

Comment: Prime factorization is surely more efficient to find the factors, but this is a nice way to determine them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both formulas base on a simple property of the sine- and the cosine-function. $$\sin{\pi x}=0$$ holds if and only if $x$ is an integer and $$|\cos{\pi x}|=1$$ holds if and only if $x$ is an integer. So, the method actually works for all $n$.